# SOBO with JWT User Integration

Tags: docusignapi

I have created a user(admin user) and using it for JWT User Integration (User Consent). Now, whenever I am sending an envelope, it is created against the JWT user.
How can I make it work like SOBO. So whenever I provide a user id other than JWT authenticated, it should create envelope against it.
Something similar to legacy header but with JWT (User Consent)

Answer (score 2):

SOBO will not work as it used to work in legacy header way. You need to get one-time consent for the user before sending envelope on that user's behalf. So with JWT, you need to either get User Consent or use Admin Consent (with claiming domain in DocuSign), once you have the consent of that user, then passing that user's userId in the JWT call will help you in getting that user's access token. This is now the only recommended way from DocuSign.

Comment: Apart from "DocuSign Organization Administration be enabled." is there any other way to get consent for all users without asking them individually.

Comment: No, Only through Admin Consent via Org Admin it can be done.